# I didn't understand why I am getting false, instead of getting true, please look into the code and help me

Tags: java, string, oop, permutation

```
import java.util.*;

class Permutationcheck {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String test = "askldfj";
        String test2 = "aksfldj";
        System.out.println(perm(test, test2));
    }

    public static boolean perm(String s, String t) {
        if (s.length() != t.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        char[] perm1 = s.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(perm1);
        char[] perm2 = t.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(perm2);
        return perm1.equals(perm2);
    }
}
```

getting false as output, how could i get true as output?
I didn't understand why I am getting false, instead of getting true, please look into the code and help me!